# Technique suggestion to render corroded pipes in 3D

Tags: opengl, graphics, graphics-programming, tessellation, visualization

We currently have a lot of data relating to cracks/corrosion/deformations in metal pipes which at present, can be viewed in a crude flat/2D application which makes the metal anomalies hard to spot.

What I would like to create is a virtual 3D pipe viewer that displays the pipe and then models all of the dents in it.

I have limited knowledge of graphics programming from University however, what I was thinking of doing is creating a height-map from the data given and then use tessellation to push/pull the vertices of the pipes mesh, similar to terrain generation techniques.

My Question(s):

- Can a tessellated square/plane be wrapped around to form a pipe (and would this approach loose accuracy)? (I've only ever manipulated vertices in the y-direction on a flat plane).
- Some of the dents are extremely small (1-5mm across/deep), would my approach be accurate enough to model these anomalies?
- Is this tessellated/terrain generation style the correct way to proceed or is there a simpler solution.

Any advise is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the 3D structure of the pipe is important to your application, I would strongly recommend against visualizing things in 3D. This requires turning the pipe to see all sides, and requires developing a UI for interacting with the pipe (rotate, zoom, change focus). These interfaces are difficult to learn, even for technical people. I have enough experience with poor interfaces to recommend that you stick to 2D whenever possible: it is much harder to screw up, and much easier to learn.

For linear pipe segments, you can easily display the whole pipe "rolled out" on the display. Highlighting corrosion/dents etc. can easily be done using lighting (i.e. normal mapping) or coloring the first/second derivative. Because a tubular pipe is very similar to a 2D plane as far as deformations go, you can simply pretend a cylindrical height map is 2D, and perform all calculations there.

If you do want to go 3D, then a plane can be mapped cylindrically, with the vertices being pushed/pulled towards the pipes axis rather than up/down. You should not lose accuracy doing this, as long as your source data is high enough resolution. Tessellation is almost certainly unnecessary, as it is unlikely that you have enough data to overwhelm a modern PC rendering just with a vertex buffer.

Comment: I disagree. 1: 3D camera navigation is hard but in case of a pipe there are only 2 important degrees of freemom. Position on (in?) the pipe and rotation. This should be easy to navigate. 2: the question specifically states that a 2D visualization does not show the dents and bumps clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward cylindrical mapping should suit your purposes readily, if you look into the equation of a circle then you can come up with a 3D vector for any point on the pipe surface using all the data you have already, and your heightfield variation simply becomes variation of the radius parameter of the function.

If visualisation is your goal, then most likely what you actually want is a shader which highlights deviations from the 'normal' plane of the pipe. Whether you do that in 2D or 3D isn't really relevant, but I can imagine a simple shader that colours in a heatmap style based on the normal of the surface at any given point would quickly let you pick out deviations in the surface. Basically you would calculate the 'ideal' normal of the surface at any given point (i.e. point directly out from the centre of the pipe). Then pick your output colour based on how much the actual normal deviates from that ideal normal. If it doesn't deviate at all, then colour it black, if it deviates along the horizontal axis then raise the R component of the output colour, if it deviates along the vertical axis then raise the B component. Scale that appropriately, and you should see dents picked out as red/blue areas on the surface, with brighter colours indicating larger / more severe dents.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a tessellated square/plane be wrapped around to form a pipe (and
>   would this approach loose accuracy)? (I've only ever manipulated
>   vertices in the y-direction on a flat plane).

It would be easiest to model a segment of a pipe as a cylinder and making an abstraction in your code so that you can think of the surface of the cylinder as a flat plane while mapping out the bumps and dents. I would be happy to give a more detailed explanation if you make this into a seperate question. Its an interesting problem that I think can be solved nicely.

> Some of the dents are extremely small (1-5mm across/deep), would my
>   approach be accurate enough to model these anomalies?

Yes if you use enough vertices and do not visualize too much of the pipe at the same time (since there is a maximum to the number of vertices a GPU render at interactive rates). You can also use shading techniques to make it more clear where these little bumps are.

> Is this tessellated/terrain generation style the correct way to
>   proceed or is there a simpler solution

I have seen this type of problem solved using these technique so I'm inclinded to say yes. However I'm not an expert.

*Small note: you see these are three questions, with three answers which is not really a good fit for this Q&A platform. If you seperate your questions and ask them again you will get better responses. Be sure to read the FAQ first!*